# in linux kernel 3.x module how can i count system calls with Kprobe?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module, kernel

i need help to write a *kernel  module* to count the linux system calls at kernel 3.x 
i want to implement this with *kprobe* but earlier ways do this with *sys_call*.
please help me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this site you may find useful details for Kprobe!
http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-tuning/cha.tuning.kprobes.html

Comment: It is always preferable to answer the actual question and then provide a link to more information instead of providing only a link where the actual answer may or may not be found.